# Is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header a browser-side or server-side security mechanism?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, security, iis, cors

We are trying to secure our public facing JSON ASMX IIS service pages from outside users / domains. It seems like setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to our specific domain should help to block requests from other domains. Is the server implementing this security or is the browser? I was thinking if it's browser-based security it could be bypassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a client-side security mechanism that actually *loosens* security, rather than strengthening it.

The [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by default prevents `example.com` from reading responses from requests to `example.org` from the user's browser, optionally with the user's cookies for `example.org`. The browser security model ensures that although the request can be made, any data in the response cannot be read by the script that initiated it.

An example is that `evil.example.edu` cannot make an AJAX request to `https://gmail.com/ajax/read_mail` and then read the email of the user who is logged into Gmail with the browser that is visiting `evil.example.edu`.

If Google wanted to allow other sites to read people's email, they would set a CORS header to loosen the Same Origin Policy to allow this.

So you are more secure by default - adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` does not lock anything down - it allows exceptions to the Same Origin Policy.

As it doesn't change anything server-side, setting the header won't affect direct requests made by an attacker to the server (e.g. using curl). Also, old browsers that do not support CORS still support the Same Origin Policy so they are still "secure by default" in this respect. (Although they *may* contain unpatched vulnerabilities that modern browsers protect against. However, that's a different story.)

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is an HTTP header sent to a browser which indicates that the content of requested site is accessible to certain origins.

> The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource. 
>   The browser must enforce this.

So, yes it is client-side. This technology is intended to protect users but not server. The server actually just sends this header and does not check the source of request.
However, it is supposed to be absolutely safe as long as a user is using any modern browser. All modern browsers *guarantee* the complying with CORS rules.

So, does CORS protect your users from unwanted cross-domain requests? Yes.
Will malefactor have a possibility to make cross-domain requests to your domain? Yes, of course. It looks like for your case it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) header.

When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to tell the browser that the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. By default, Site B's pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header opens a door for cross-origin access by specific requesting origins.

For more details you can refer [Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

There is a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) which will help you in development.